# toshiba tecra m3-s636 fan control

Tags: fancontrol

I cant seem to figure out how to control my fanspeed.  The laptop is getting too hot and shutting down after i upgraded to new 12.04 ubuntu.  The fan does not sound like it is running as fast as normal.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this if you are only using Ubuntu:

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737
```

If you can use a different operating system (Windows) try AMD Overdrive for an AMD processor machine or Speed fan otherwise:

```
http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php
```

Comment: i am running straight ubuntu.  nothing else.  When i go to the link and try what it says it keeps telling me i need to be in root to perform??  Please help

Comment: To be in the root user use: `sudo su` or just preceed all commands with `sudo` to execute as if you were root without actually being root.

Comment: mike@mike-laptop:~$ pwmconfig
File /var/run/fancontrol.pid exists. This typically means that the
fancontrol deamon is running. You should stop it before running pwmconfig.
If you are certain that fancontrol is not running, then you can delete
/var/run/fancontrol.pid manually.
mike@mike-laptop:~$ 

this is the message i am getting now.  Any ideas?

Comment: Delete it. Run the same command again.